# Android App reopen from background state

Tags: android

Is there any way to identify the app is started from the scratch (i.e **not** already in memory) or from background (already opened a app and hit the `home` button)?

Comment: as 

@Keyboardsurfer says try to understand that i seems you are searching for onResume() ok

Comment: @ReddyRaaz To make the answer of Keyboardsurfer more clearly: So this means: When you start an app from "scratch", it will start at the `onCreate()` function.  
When you start it from the background, it won't go trough `onCreate()`  
So just put a check if it runs trough the `onCreate()` function.  
If yes, app started from scratch, else app started from background

Comment: @ BigFlow. : Thanks for the response. But I mean to check the entire Application state. not a single Activity.

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean Application and not Activity, then you should create a class derived from android.app.Application object and declare this class in manifest to be able to monitor its lifecycle through overriden methods.
One object of this type is created each time your application starts from the scratch, so if you need to save some data across application lifecycle, this object or any kind of singleton is a good way of doing so.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know when an APP is returning from background state (when you return to home or another app and back to your app again) maybe this can help you.
if you find a case when this do not apply, please let me know.

---

```
public class FatherClass extends Activity {

      private static int activities = 0;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String clase) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      }

      protected void onRestart(){
           super.onRestart();
           if(activities == 0){
                 Log.i("APP","BACK FROM BACKGROUND");
           }
      }

      protected void onStop(){
           super.onStop();
           activities = activities - 1;
      }

      protected void onStart(){
           super.onStart();
           activities = activities + 1;
      }
}
```

---

All of your Activities MUST extend from this one.

And is simple, if your main activity executes the onCreate() (the method in the activity you want, not the onCreate on my example) and you never call it from within another activity (think about it like a splash screen) then you are starting from scratch, but if your activity executes the onRestart() and the counter "activities" value is 0 "zero", then you are returning form a background state, i hope this can help you and is not to late for another person.

Answer (score 1):

The whole code should be written in an app specefic super Activity

```
        boolean isForeground = isInForeground(this);

        if ((!hasFocus) && (!isForeground)) {
            context.isBackground = true;
            Log.v("Alalytics", "Background...");
        }
        else if (context.isBackground) {
            context.isBackground = false;
            Log.v("Alalytics", "Forground...");
        }
```

Then... create method to check weather the app is foreground or background

/**
     * Checks whether the app is in foreground or not
     * 
     * @param context the context
     * @return true, if is in foreground
     ** /

```
private boolean isInForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (appProcesses == null) {
        return false;
    }
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
        if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND
                && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments due to low reputation, so I'll add new answer for Reddy Raaz:
This way you need additional permission which might discourage some users from installing the app.
The framework really calls Application.onCreate method only when it gets started from scratch. This way you can get the information reliably and without additional permission.